# Private blogging server in ubuntu18.04

Tags: blog

Is there any way to create an internal blogging setup which would be accessible only to my hosts?

I want to make a private server in Ubuntu 18.04 where I'll be able to write blogs and only my hosts will be able to view blogs.

Comment: .htaccess & .htpasswd are probably what you are looking for. This link is helpful https://www.whoishostingthis.com/resources/htaccess/

Comment: @kingmilo Thanks. But I am not getting it. Is there anything like deploying Wordpress on private server for internal blogging ??

Comment: don't think of it as private blogging application, what you need to get a better understanding of is networking and firewalls. You can make any application private or public on your server, it all comes down to how you setup the network and firewall around it. You would need to provide more information about your current setup if you would like more guidance. For example when you say "your hosts" do you mean devices on the same LAN, or do you mean specific devices outside of your LAN, the configuration will be different depending on your answer :)

Comment: IPTables too will allow only IP's that you configure....https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/iptables-tutorial

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you simply want a private web server with Wordpress installed on it. You would need to install a LAMP stack on a Ubuntu server or laptop or even a Raspberry Pi, and then install Wordpress.

Comment: Thanks all. :-) I liked the focus point of Firewall said by kingmilo & EODCraft Staff.

Comment: @Jos I liked your solution. Thanks :-)